# auto filling mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, database, autofill

i want to fill database automatically using python 
i have table with 4 columns
id name lastname mobile number
i am taking input of name and last name from text file.
here is what i m trying

```
with open("names.txt") as f:
    word=f.read()
    word=word.split()
with open ("last name.txt") as l:
    wordx=l.read().split()
    print(wordx)
for (i,j,k) in zip(range(3,12),word,wordx):
    insertdata="insert into person(id,firstname,lastname,mobileno) values ('%d','%r','%r','%d')"%(i,tuple(word),tuple(wordx),randint(0000000000, 9999999999))
    cursor.execute(insertdata)
    connectionvar.commit()
```

im getting this error
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer :)

```
with open("names.txt") as f:
    word=f.read()
    word=word.split()
with open ("last name.txt") as l:
    wordx=l.read().split()
    print(wordx)
for (j,k) in zip(word,wordx):
    insertdata="insert into person(firstname,lastname,mobileno) values ('%s','%s','%d')"%(j,k,randint(0000000000, 999999999))
    cursor.execute(insertdata)
    connectionvar.commit()
```